# JSF: when disable component, its value does not make into the request map parameter. Is there a workaround?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a drop down list `p:selectonemenu` and a checkbox `p:selectbooleancheckbox`, when I select the checkbox, I want to set the `selectonemenu` to a specific value. And I dont want the user to change it, so I set `selectonemenu` `disabled` attribute to `true`. However, when it is disabled, its value does not appear inside the request parameter map, when I do `facescontext.getcurrentinstance().getexternalcontext().getrequestparametermap()`, and I need its value to this map. Is there a way to get around this?

I writing a font-end to a legacy Servlet system, where they use request map parameters to obtain form attribute value.

Comment: It doesn't appear because when the component is disabled, the browser doesn't send the components value to the server. Look for "readonly" parameter.

Comment: @AdrianMitev: Unfortunately, even though JSF component `h:selectonemenu` have `readonly` attribute, primefaces component `p:selectonemenu` does not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Adrian Mitev pointed out in a comment, disabling the `selectBooleanCheckbox` component will mean it will not post its value on a form submit.

What you can do however is have a hidden input field where you can set the value to the same managed bean property as the checkbox.

```
<h:inputHidden id="checkDisabled" value="#{managedBean.someValue}" />
```

Using a javascript you can set the value of this hidden input when the checkbox is disabled.

Comment: This does by the way not specifically apply to checkboxes, but to all HTML input elements and buttons in general. If `disabled="true"`, then its name=value will not be sent as request parameter. This is as per [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1): *"Disabled controls cannot be successful."*

Comment: @BalusC: The above problem also give me trouble, since JSF component dont have `name` attribute (I think you set the `name` but setting the `id`), and if I set the `id` attribute of the `<h:inputHidden>` component, to be the same as the `selectonemenu`, then I got this exception `Component ID cmbxFgnFormNumber has already been found in the view`

Comment: The ID get generated as name. Check HTML source. As to the new problem, either give the disabled checkbox a different ID, or use plain `<input type="hidden">` instead (this won't prepend the form ID).