# h:selectManyCheckbox loses values when navigating

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My problem is that h:selectManyCheckbo loses values when navigating , here's my code below :

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="selectGroupsBox" 
                      value="{userCreationWizardBean.selectedGroupsId}"
                      layout="pageDirection">

                            <f:selectItems var="Group"
                                value="#{userCreationWizardBean.terminalsGroups}"
                                itemLabel="#{terminalsGroup.groupName}"
                                itemValue="#{terminalsGroup.id}"
                                itemDisabled="#{Group.defaultGroup}">
                            </f:selectItems>
                            <p:ajax event="change" update=":form-top-wizard:numBase" process="selectGroupsBox"
                                listener="#{userCreationWizardBean.selectedGroupListner}"></p:ajax>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

The CheckBox loses values if I go back and forth using my navigation pad :

```
<div id="top-wizard" class="#{class}">
        <ul>
            <li class="premier#{wizard_step=='0'?'_active':''}"><p:commandLink
                    action="#{userCreationWizardBean.getViewAt(0)}" ajax="true"
                    update=":msg-form:popup_faces-messages" 
                    /></li>

            <li class="deuxieme#{wizard_step=='1'?'_active':''}"><p:commandLink
                    action="#{userCreationWizardBean.getViewAt(1)}" ajax="true"
                    update=":msg-form:popup_faces-messages"  
                     /></li>

            <li class="troisieme#{wizard_step=='2'?'_active':''}"><p:commandLink
                    action="#{userCreationWizardBean.getViewAt(2)}" ajax="true"
                     update=":msg-form:popup_faces-messages"  
                     /></li>
            <li class="quatrieme#{wizard_step=='3'?'_active':''}"><p:commandLink
                    action="#{userCreationWizardBean.getViewAt(3)}" ajax="true"
                    update=":msg-form:popup_faces-messages" 
                    /></li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

The problem stragely vanishes when I delete the itemDisabled attribute.

it seems like i can use jquery css selector syntaxe to exclude the checkbox from being processed , but only in primefaces 3.3 , but i'm using 3.2.

Comment: itemDisabled="Group.defaultGroup)) }" is this an error just here in SO post or is it in your code ?

Comment: sorry i just misstyped it

Comment: What scope type are you using in the referred ManagedBean?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are experiencing has to do with the fact that a  disabled component or item's value is not sent to the server.. I Have also been trying to find a workaround. check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021634/jsf-when-disable-component-its-value-does-not-make-into-the-request-map-parame#_=_) it might be helpful.