# How to "grey-out" <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> without disable?

Tags: jsf, disabled-input, selectbooleancheckbox

I have a checkbox:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checkboxValue}"/>
```

Based on a given scenario, I need to grey-out the box and prevent the user from modifying it. I know disable will do this, but the issue is that disable prevents POST and I need to send the value to my bean whether or not the box is greyed-out.

Is there a way to grey-out and prevent user input without disable?

Comment: You can use the `readonly` attribute and play with css to grey the check box out

Comment: Look at this answer. Hope it helps  :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021634/jsf-when-disable-component-its-value-does-not-make-into-the-request-map-parame

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but to populate the checkbox, the value is in the backing bean, so if it is not send to the bean,it still is there or do I miss something

Answer (score 1):

may be you try this:

1 - Put a styleClass="make-disabled" in your booleanCheckBox;
2 - Use a jquery function to disabled only in view context :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//disabled all checks with class make-disabled
$('input[type=checkbox].make-disabled').attr('disabled','disabled');

//configure before submit form to enabled all checks with class make-disabled to send do request
jQuery('#yourFormId').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox].make-disabled').attr('disabled',false);
});});
```

Sorry my english. I'm brazilian. This example help you?