# How to check if a component in PrimeFaces is disabled?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I would like to know how to check if a component (ex. p:inputText, p:password, and etc.) is disabled in PrimeFaces through Java? Because I plan on processing my form dynamically depending on the state (disabled/enabled) of the component. I know about PartialSubmit in PrimeFaces but to use it, you have to type the ID of the component you only want to process, which I don't want since I'm hardcoding the components I will process. Thank you.

I'm using PrimeFaces-6.2.RC2.jar and JSF 2.2.16 Mojarra.

Comment: If there's a reason a component is disabled, why don't you use that same reason (condition) to check *whether* it is disabled?

Comment: I want to check the state of the component through Java. I looked up the documentation of UIComponent Class but there is no method to determine the state (whether it is disabled/enabled) of the component.

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  If your component has something like `disabled="#{bean.shouldDisable or bean.shouldDeactivate}"` or something like that, you can use those same conditions to check whether it's disabled, both from Java and from the jsf. If you mean that it's been disabled by code on the frontend (e.g. JavaScript) that's a different matter, and I would specify that in the question.

Comment: Partial submit can also use [SEF](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/search.xhtml), so you don't need to hard-code id's. Oh and btw, iirc, ['jsf' does not submit values of disabled components by default...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021634/jsf-when-disable-component-its-value-does-not-make-into-the-request-map-parame)

Comment: I see! Thank you FedericoklezCulloca and Kukeltje for your answers.

Comment: Control the states of your components manually and individually with boolean variables in your managedBean.